# How to test if string is equal to "x" || "X"?

Tags: java, string, equals

```
    String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Pick a conversion to do:\nGrade");
    if (c.equals("grade")||("Grade"))
```

I want it to start if the user enters grade or Grade not just grade, but when I use this I get a error. How would I fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem:  You're using `||` improperly.  [It expects, on both sides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24), something of type `boolean` to be present.

From the JLS:

> Each operand of the conditional-or operator must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

Since `"Grade"` isn't a boolean (but `c.equals("grade")` *is*), this becomes a compile-time error.

While you *could* fix it by correcting the boolean on the right hand side...

```
if(c.equals("grade") || c.equals("Grade"))
```

...why not do it in a more straightforward way?

```
if(c.equalsIgnoreCase("grade"))
```

This particular `equals` on String was likely engineered for this use case (or other use cases, as "GrAde" would fail your check too).  It will perform a length check on your strings first, then a case insensitive comparison on each element.

Comment: Thanks, kinda easy once I view it, I wanna smack myself lol. beginner coder for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put an || statement in the middle of a method call like that.

```
if (c.equals("grade")||c.equals("Grade")){
    //do stuff
}
```

There are other ways to accomplish your task, IE using other methods, but your problem is coming form a misuse of the || operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
if (c.toLowerCase().equals("grade")) { }
```

Comment: This is what I'd go for too.

Comment: Wouldn't c.equalsIgnoreCase() be better than c.toLowerCase().equals ? Any comments on that?